# Could I get an explanation for the telescoping series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, telescopic-series

I am confused on how to solve a $S_N$ using a telescoping series. I don't know where the $\frac{1}{N+1}$ comes from.

The problem reads,

Let S = $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2})$

and the result should be $S_N = \frac {3}{2} - \frac {1} {N+1} - \frac {1} {N+2}$

Comment: What attempt have you made? Did you try to write out the terms of the sum?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks, I will change it, and nothing, because I don't know what steps to even take because it doesn't make sense to me. That's why I asked for an explanation and a walk through.

Comment: You have only defined $S$ and you are asking for $S_N$.  Define $S_N$ first. The  take some small value for $N$, say $N=2,3$ and see what you get.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy okay, I'll start with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the sum and you will notice that absolutely all the terms except the first two and the last one cancel each other out (this is not super very easy to see, by the way):

$$\require{cancel}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right)=
\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+
\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}\right)+\\
\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}\right)+\cdots+
\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{N+2}\right)=\\
\left(1-\cancel{\frac{1}{3}}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\cancel{\frac{1}{4}}\right)+
\left(\cancel{\frac{1}{3}}-\cancel{\frac{1}{5}}\right)+\left(\cancel{\frac{1}{4}}-\cancel{\frac{1}{6}}\right)+\\
\left(\cancel{\frac{1}{5}}-\cancel{\frac{1}{7}}\right)+\left(\cancel{\frac{1}{6}}-\cancel{\frac{1}{8}}\right)+\cdots+
\left(\cancel{\frac{1}{n}} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right)=\\
1+\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{n+2}=\frac{3}{2}- \frac{1}{n+2}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{3}{2}-0=\frac{3}{2}.
$$

So, this series adds up to $\frac{3}{2}$.

I think the user *herb steinberg* has got it right. I'll just expand on his answer a little bit:

$$\require{cancel}
S_N=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right)=
\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n} - \sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n+2}=
\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n} - \sum\limits_{n=3}^{N+2}\frac{1}{n}=\\
\left(1+\frac12+\cancel{\frac13}+\cancel{\frac14}+\cancel{\frac15}+\cdots+\cancel{\frac1N}\right)+\left(-
\cancel{\frac13}-\cancel{\frac14}-\cancel{\frac15}+\cdots-\cancel{\frac1N}-\frac{1}{N+1}-\frac{1}{N+2}\right)=\\
1+\frac12-\frac{1}{N+1}-\frac{1}{N+2}=
\frac32-\frac{1}{N+1}-\frac{1}{N+2}.
$$

This is a much better way to see how the cancellation process takes place.

Comment: Alright, I see that, but I'm still wondering where the $\frac {1} {N+1}$ comes from.

Comment: It should not be there because the last expression is $\frac1n-\frac{1}{n+2}$. $\frac1n$ gets canceled and the only thing you're left with is $-\frac{1}{n+2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2})$  The second term can be rewritten as $\sum_{n=3}^{N+2}\frac{1}{n}$  Combine the two parts to get $S_N=1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{N+1}-\frac{1}{N+2}\to \frac{3}{2}$, as $N \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

To get a closed form of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2})$ we write down the some first and some last summands.

$$\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{1+2}+\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2+2}+\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3+2}+\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4+2}+\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{5+2}+...$$

$$ +\frac{1}{N-3} - \frac{1}{N-1}+\frac{1}{N-2} - \frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N-1} - \frac{1}{N+1}+\frac{1}{N} - \frac{1}{N+2}$$

$$=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{1}} - \frac{1}{3}+\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}} - \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7}+...$$

$$ +\frac{1}{N-3} - \frac{1}{N-1}+\frac{1}{N-2} - \frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N-1}\color{blue}{ - \frac{1}{N+1}}+\frac{1}{N} \color{blue}{- \frac{1}{N+2}}$$

The blue terms are left over. This is $\frac32- \frac{1}{N+1}-\frac{1}{N+2}$

Answer (score 0):

Just write
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2}) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^N (\frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1} -\frac{1}{n+2}) = $$ 
$$\underbrace{\sum\limits_{n=1}^N (\frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{n+1})}_{=1- \frac{1}{N+1}} + \underbrace{\sum\limits_{n=1}^N(\frac{1}{n+1} -\frac{1}{n+2})}_{=\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{N+2}} = \frac{3}{2}- \frac{1}{N+1}  - \frac{1}{N+2}$$